# Java File Input/Output. Letter Occurances in a given File

Tags: java, file, file-io

my problem is:

Write a program that prompts the user to enter a file name and display the occurrences of each letter in the file. Must use exceptions. Letters are not case-sensitive.

**Here is a sample run:**

```
Enter the File name: example.txt

The Occurrence of A's is 11
The Occurrence of B's is 2
....
The Occurrence of Y's is 3
The Occurrence of Z's is 2.
```

My code was made thinking I had to be case sensitive which I do not have to be. So how do I change my code to include all letters and not just Capital letter. I do not have much time to solve it myself which is why i posted it here:

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class LetterOccurance
 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
    File file = new File(new Scanner(System.in).next());

    if (!file.exists()) 
    {
        System.out.println(file + " doesn't exist");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String buffer = "";
    int[] letterCount = new int[26];
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) 
    {

        while (input.hasNext()) 
        {
            buffer = input.nextLine();
            for (char ch : buffer.toCharArray())
            {
                ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
                if (isLetter(ch)) 
                {
                    letterCount[ch - 'A']++;
                }
            }

        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < letterCount.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println((char)(i + 'A') + " occurrence = " + letterCount[i]);
    }

}

private static boolean isLetter(char ch) 
{

    return (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
}
}
```

Comment: You are by using toUpperCase(). If you want to store lowercase counts, you could test for Character.isUpperCase() or isLowerCase() then store.

Comment: *"I do not have much time to solve it myself which is why i posted it here. "* - We are not a free testing / debugging service.  Debugging is >>your<< job.  If you have a specific question about a specific problem with your code, fee free to ask it.  But for what it is worth, I don't >>see<< any problems with the code you have written.

Comment: @Dakoda I want to count how many times the letter occurs in the file both lower case and upper case. The code i have so far only counts upper case letters. So how would it look like in code if I wanted to find the total amount of occurences.

Comment: I'm confused...your code already does exactly what you want it to do. If there is the letter **"A"** regardless of its letter case it is added for that character. This is for the simple reason that you convert each character within each read string you iterate through to uppercase and compare it to another uppercase character within the **isLetter()** method.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I realized that my mistake was that I was comparing the wrong text file with what the given output was supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can either choose to use upper or lowercase. Whichever you use, you do the same for the text your're looking at and the text you'r comparing too. So you would do toUpperCase() (or lower) on the string from the file and then look for upper (or lowercase) letters

Comment: I want to count occurrences of both an upper and lower case letter. So how would combine the count in the code. And what would it look like in code @BrianPipa

Comment: You don't count both separately, you count both at the same time by calling toLowerCase() or toUpperCase()

Comment: Oh I see now. It works either way by calling either method. I was also having trouble because I was reading the wrong text file and comparing it to the given answer.